# Why voip push notification is not received on device when iOS application is closed or terminated?

Tags: ios, push-notification, voip

Hai I have a iOS application which is used for voip to voip call. App works fine when app is in background and foreground but not when app is terminated(I swiped up the app).After I swipe up the app,I am not able to see the log on xcode so I am not sure whether push notification is recived or not.But Incoming call is not notified.

```
 func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType ,completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
          callkitProvider!.reportNewIncomingCall(with: xxxCallKitController.uuid!,
                        update: callUpdate, completion: { (error) in
                            completion()
          })
    }
```

I tested with IoS 12.4.7 and 14.0.1. Got same result. How do I fix it.Any hint will be helpful for me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: We are also facing the same problem, we did testing in iOS 12.4.9, and the voip notification is receiving in background state, But not in app terminate state.Any updates on this